# Nginx headers for Delphi or Freepascal

Tags: delphi, nginx, freepascal

Are there any nginx headers translated for Delphi/FreePascal?

Comment: What do you mean by "translated for" ? What are you trying to achieve ? To serve a webapp written in Delphi ?

Comment: nginx is a web server for anybody who didn't notice. No I haven't seen any Nginx integrations for Delphi. However it uses standard fastcgi, so I'm not sure why you would need nginx-specific headers. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Artimuz Warren already said what I was going to (:

Comment: @WarrenP I want to write a module for nginx

Comment: @WarrenP not sure that I got you, but I've googled for quite some time before giving up and trying SO.

Comment: Next time, please take some time to write a more detailled question. Here, is not clear at all that you speak about Nginx third-party module development...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to write a Nginx Module, then it seems that you have to write it in C.

Indeed modules seems to be compiled at the same time that the core, written in C. A [guide to Nginx module development is here](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#components)

I guess you *could* theorically write your module in another language, if your language can compile shared libraries... but it would involve a deep understanding and customization of the nginx compile toolchain.

Comment: +1 thank you for your time, it seems that my hunch was right... I haven't found anywhere(yet) saying that "shared modules" is not "there yet" like in apache... basically that's what I wanted, I don't want to compile it with "built in" modules ):

Comment: You could write a simple stub in C that loads a Delphi DLL though, right. But I thought that nginx would already have such a thing.